# JS confirm and onsubmit not working

Tags: javascript, html

This is my JS:

```
function confirmPurchase(){
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to purchase the ticket?');
    return answer;
}

function init(){
    purchaseForm.onsubmit = confirmPurchase;    
}
```

but when I click "cancel" on the alertbox, it is still submitting the form. How can I stop the submission of form on "cancel" and only allow the submission when "OK" is clicked?

Comment: please add a fiddle including the form markup etc

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: is this something u r looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/TEKRL/

Comment: Is that the ***EXACT*** code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('myForm'),
    confirmPurchasePrompt = function(e) {
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to purchase the ticket?');

        if (!answer) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    };


form.addEventListener('submit', confirmPurchasePrompt, true);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8Y3/

Note that this will only work in modern browsers (IE > 8), but this is the general idea. I'm sure you can make it compatible with older versions with some research.

Actually, this could help:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners

or this:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/addeventlistner-polyfill/

of eve this:
https://gist.github.com/eirikbacker/2864711

Answer (score 0):

First the form

```
<form action="/" id="myform">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then JS:

```
function confirmPurchase(){
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to purchase the ticket?');
    return answer;
}

function init(){
    var purchaseForm = document.getElementById('myform');
    purchaseForm.onsubmit = confirmPurchase;    
}

init();
```

working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TEKRL/

Comment: How is it different from OPs code other than you showed how `purchaseForm` is declared?